# Incrementing pause value in loop_control

Tags: ansible

I'd like to increment the value of the pause in loop_control. Any ideas how to increment +1 for each host? Also, how about incrementing it after X number of hosts? For example, if X = 3 and ansible_play_hosts = 12, then I would expect the values of pause to be 0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3.

Edit: Here is an example of what I'm trying to do, where `incrementing_delay` increments by 1 each time, or it increments by one after every three hosts.

```
- name: do a loop
  debug:
    msg: "index0 = {{ ansible_loop.index0 }}"
  delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
  run_once: true
  loop_control:
    extended: yes
    pause: "{{ incrementing_delay }}"
```

Comment: The use-case is not clear. See my answer how to create the sequence. Try to suggest the code and expected result.

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *"If X = 3 and ansible_play_hosts = 12, then I would expect the values of pause to be 0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3"*

A: Is this probably what are you looking for?

```
  vars:
    X: 3
  tasks:
    - name: do a loop
      debug:
        msg: "pause = {{ (ansible_loop.index0/X)|int }}"
      delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
      run_once: true
      loop_control:
        extended: yes
```

(not tested)

Note, because of *`run_once: true`*, *`delegate_to`* delegates the task to the first item in the list *`ansible_play_hosts`*. This makes the directive effectively

```
      delegate_to: "{{ ansible_play_hosts.0 }}"
```

Comment: This is much closer but not quite there yet. I want to actually pause the loop for the specified number of seconds (0 seconds for the first three iterations, 1 second for the next three iterations, etc.). Unfortunately I cannot seem to use ansible_loop.index0 in the pause parameter.

Comment: `not quite there yet`. What about the question?

Comment: I'm sorry but what is the question? Your example does give the desired values, but I need those values to be used in the pause parameter of loop_control.